# How to create a USB flash drive that looks for all bootloaders on hard drives

Tags: boot, usb, multi-boot

I have two SSDs, one has Windows 10 (version 2004), the other has Ubuntu 21.04. Disks have EFI partitions, each disk has its own OS loader.

I need to create a USB flash drive, booting from which I would be able to choose which disk to boot from now. How can I do that? (This is required because every time you change the OS, it takes a long time to enter BIOS and change the priority of loading disks.)

Comment: Why not add Windows to the Grub boot manager Ubuntu most likely already has?

Comment: You are looking for the entirely wrong solution to a problem that is already solved. Windows and Ubuntu already have bootloaders that can handle this. Please look up bootloaders and how to configure them for existing OS installs.

Comment: Its a bad qusstion - so the bad answer is to use supergrub - which will look for the available boot devices. That said, the appropriate answer us as per the comments above.